# Unknown column error when using pluck

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

**Controller**

```
@communities = current_user.get_up_voted(Community).pluck(:id) 
@codes = Code.includes(:user).where(:community_id => @communities).order('users.last_active_at DESC').page(params[:page]).per(10)
```

I get this error

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (Mysql2::Error: Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous: SELECT id FROM communities` INNER JOIN votes ON votes.votable_id = communities.id AND votes.votable_type = 'Community' WHERE votes.voter_id = 2 AND votes.voter_type = 'User' AND votes.vote_flag = 1 AND (communities.deleted_at IS NULL)):
```

**UPDATE1(SQL Query with Patriot's code)**

```
SELECT  `codes`.`id` AS t0_r0, `codes`.`user_id` AS t0_r1, `codes`.`community_id` AS t0_r2, `codes`.`invisible` AS t0_r3, `codes`.`code` AS t0_r4, `codes`.`greeting` AS t0_r5, `codes`.`created_at` AS t0_r6, `codes`.`updated_at` AS t0_r7, `codes`.`deleted_at` AS t0_r8, `codes`.`notification` AS t0_r9, `codes`.`wanted` AS t0_r10, `users`.`id` AS t1_r0, `users`.`email` AS t1_r1, `users`.`encrypted_password` AS t1_r2, `users`.`username` AS t1_r3, `users`.`reset_password_token` AS t1_r4, `users`.`reset_password_sent_at` AS t1_r5, `users`.`remember_created_at` AS t1_r6, `users`.`sign_in_count` AS t1_r7, `users`.`current_sign_in_at` AS t1_r8, `users`.`last_sign_in_at` AS t1_r9, `users`.`current_sign_in_ip` AS t1_r10, `users`.`last_sign_in_ip` AS t1_r11, `users`.`banned` AS t1_r12, `users`.`confirmation_token` AS t1_r13, `users`.`confirmed_at` AS t1_r14, `users`.`confirmation_sent_at` AS t1_r15, `users`.`unconfirmed_email` AS t1_r16, `users`.`created_at` AS t1_r17, `users`.`updated_at` AS t1_r18, `users`.`deleted_at` AS t1_r19, `users`.`last_active_at` AS t1_r20, `users`.`comments_count` AS t1_r21, `users`.`follows_count` AS t1_r22, `users`.`codes_count` AS t1_r23, `users`.`communities_count` AS t1_r24, `users`.`nomail` AS t1_r25, `users`.`point_added_at` AS t1_r26, `user_profiles`.`id` AS t2_r0, `user_profiles`.`user_id` AS t2_r1, `user_profiles`.`language_id` AS t2_r2, `user_profiles`.`country_id` AS t2_r3, `user_profiles`.`prefecture_id` AS t2_r4, `user_profiles`.`gender_id` AS t2_r5, `user_profiles`.`nickname` AS t2_r6, `user_profiles`.`introduction` AS t2_r7, `user_profiles`.`picture_url` AS t2_r8, `user_profiles`.`created_at` AS t2_r9, `user_profiles`.`updated_at` AS t2_r10, `user_profiles`.`deleted_at` AS t2_r11, `user_profiles`.`user_avatar_file_name` AS t2_r12, `user_profiles`.`user_avatar_content_type` AS t2_r13, `user_profiles`.`user_avatar_file_size` AS t2_r14, `user_profiles`.`user_avatar_updated_at` AS t2_r15, `user_profiles`.`age` AS t2_r16, `user_profiles`.`activity_invisible` AS t2_r17, `user_profiles`.`total_point` AS t2_r18, `user_profiles`.`bonus_point` AS t2_r19, `user_profiles`.`introduction_html` AS t2_r20, `user_profiles`.`title` AS t2_r21, `user_profiles`.`next_level` AS t2_r22, `user_profiles`.`invitation` AS t2_r23, `user_profiles`.`notification` AS t2_r24, `user_profiles`.`notification_time` AS t2_r25, `user_profiles`.`wall_time` AS t2_r26, `user_profiles`.`wall_flag` AS t2_r27, `user_profiles`.`wanted_at` AS t2_r28, `user_profiles`.`wanted_message` AS t2_r29 FROM `codes` LEFT OUTER JOIN `users` ON `users`.`id` = `codes`.`user_id` LEFT OUTER JOIN `user_profiles` ON `user_profiles`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` WHERE `codes`.`community_id` IN (6, 2, 9, 1, 8, 16, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 30, 29, 67, 66, 5, 87) AND (`codes`.`deleted_at` IS NULL) ORDER BY users.last_active_at DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

**UPDATE2**

code

```
@communities = current_user.get_up_voted(Community)
@codes = Code.includes(:user).where(:community_id => @communities.collect(&:id)).order('created_at DESC').page(params[:page]).per(10)
```

SQL Query

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (Mysql2::Error: Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous: SELECT id FROM `communities` INNER JOIN `votes` ON `votes`.`votable_id` = `communities`.`id` AND `votes`.`votable_type` = 'Community' WHERE `votes`.`voter_id` = 2 AND `votes`.`voter_type` = 'User' AND `votes`.`vote_flag` = 1 AND (`communities`.`deleted_at` IS NULL)):
```

Comment: The DB doesn't know which `id` column to select -- the one from `users `or the one from `communities`. So how about `current_user.get_up_voted(Community).pluck('users.id')`?

Comment: @pdobb not 'communities.id'? because its trying to get array of communities ids

Comment: If you want to get community ids back then your query should start from the Community model not the User model.

Comment: @pdobb How can I change my code?  But I think this code `current_user.get_up_voted(Community)` helps giving me community ids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just because you called that column `id` which is no way to access it. it happens when the column name appears many times in resulting table (usually in case of `join`)

e.g: like this if i join `users` table and `user_ranks` table.

```
id | name   | email     | id       | rank | user_id
1  | 'pari' | 'x@g.com' | `rank_id`| 12   | 1
```

You can solve this problem by calling the field name explicitly something like

```
current_user.get_up_voted(Community).pluck('communities.id')
```

Comment: I tried your answer. But now it returns this error `NoMethodError (undefined method `id' for 6:Fixnum):
`

Comment: I like to see from where that error is occurring. The error backtrace look like this http://www.infoq.com/resource/news/2008/09/rails-exc-getex-hoptoad/en/resources/ht-error-backtrace.png

Comment: oops. sorry your code works fine!! my bad! Thanks. But it still takes about 30 secs to finish loading a page:( really slow

Comment: if that works, please accept the answer. You know how much important it is. Thanks :)

Comment: @PatrioshPiplewar I've just updated my question. Please take a look. With your code, it takes about 30 secs to finish loading because it outputs long query just like **UPDATE1**. However, If I use `collect()` instead it doesn't take that long and it only output short query like **UPDATE2** Can you make your code something like **UPDATE2**?

Comment: Ohh, i am sorry. I dont understand the relation between this tables so cant help . Post new question and tag `mysql` ..may be some mysql guy will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a scope on Community like `upvoted_by`? E.g. `Community.upvoted_by(user)`? If so (or if you add one) then you can do:

```
Community.upvoted_by(user).pluck(:id)
```

to get a list of these community ids. But, I think the best answer is to let ActiveRecord and ARel shoulder some of the burden for you. You can `.merge` a scope like this:

```
# community.rb
scope :upvoted_by, -> user { where(user_id: user) }

# controller
Code.includes(user: { :communities }).merge(Community.upvoted_by(user)).order('users.last_active_at DESC').page(params[:page]).per(10)
```

Comment: no I don't have `upvoted_by`  I use this gem for that `acts_as_votable https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable`

Comment: Ahh, I see. Then maybe not so much.

Comment: It sounds like my answer is moot at this point. You can accept [Paritosh's Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24111370/171183) if it works for you :).